# CSV file output base on selected month

Tags: php, mysql, csv

index.php

I want to export the data based on the selected month

```
<div id="page-wrapper">

        <div class="container-fluid">


    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Schedule Management</h2><hr />
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="btn-add"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> &nbsp; Add Schedule</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="btn-view"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> &nbsp; View Schedule</button>
    <hr />

    <div class="content-loader">
           <form method="post" action="index.php">
   Select a month <select name="months"  onchange ='this.form.submit()'>
    <option value="0"> </option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>

</form>
    <table cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive">

    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Sched #</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Check In Date</th>
    <th>Check Out Date</th>
    <th>Room Rate</th>
    <th>Reservation Fee</th>
    <th>Date Paid</th>
    <th>Mode of Paymnet</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>edit</th>
    <th>delete</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    require_once 'dbconfig.php';

    if(isset($_POST['months'])){ $months = $_POST['months']; }else { $months='';}
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblguest WHERE MONTH(checkin) = '".$months."' "); 
    //this is my solution to filter my table data base on the selected months in the index.php table

    $stmt->execute();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['fname']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['lname']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['checkin']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['checkout']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['rrate']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['reservefee']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['datepaid']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['modepayment']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['stats']; ?></td>
        <td align="center">
        <a id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="edit-link" href="#" title="Edit">
        <img src="edit.png" width="20px" />
        </a></td>
        <td align="center"><a id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="delete-link" href="#" title="Delete">
        <img src="delete.png" width="20px" />
        </a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <a class="btn" href="export.php">Export</a>
    </div>

</div>

<br />

<div class="container">



</div>
```

export.php

the export button is working but I want to filter my data just like in my table in index.php based on month selected......but right now I can only perform when I click on export button the whole data on my database get an output to the .csv

```
    <?php
  require_once 'dbconfig.php';


 header('Content-Type: text/csv');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=exported-data.csv');

 $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblguest ");

 $stmt->execute();


$filename = date('d.m.Y').'.csv';

$data = fopen($filename, 'w');


  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$csv = implode(',', $row) . "\n";
fwrite($data, $csv);
print_r($csv);
}

 echo "\r\n";

fclose($data);

 ?>
```

Comment: Add the parameters to URL, on selecting any option. This way you would be able to make the link according to city and you can get the parameter using $_GET parameter, or the your application way.

Comment: Please have a look, I wrote the answer, If you find good then you can mark it as accepted and up-vote it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code. You first need to select the data base on you condition.

Set a Select drop down button in You HTML, with the Day parameter in Get request.

```
    <label>Day</label>
    <select id='lead_ids' name='lead_ids' onchange="location = this.value;">
        <option value=""> ... </option>
        <option value="search"> All </option>
        <option value="search?day=Monday">{{ Monday }}</option>
        <option value="search?day=Tuesday">{{ Tuesday }}</option>
    </select>
```

This way you would be able to make the link according to city and you can get the parameter using $_GET parameter, or the your application way.

```
    $q = "SELECT * FROM tblguest";
    if(!empty($_GET('day'))) {
        $q .= ' WHERE day= ' . $_GET('day');
    }
     $stmt = $db_con->prepare($q);

    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $result[] = $row;
    }
    $file_name = "downloads/".date('dmY_His').".csv";
   // call the csv export
    exportToCsv($result, $file_name);
```

This way you can add multiple condition with different parameters.

Call this function to export it to CSV.

```
function exportToCsv($array, $file_name = "export.csv", $delimiter=";") {
        $f = fopen($file_name, "w");
        $head = array_keys($array[0]);

        fputcsv($f, $head);
        foreach ($array as $line) {
            fputcsv($f, $line);
        }

        if (file_exists($file_name))
        {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: text/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file_name));
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_name));
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile($file_name);
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Please mark the answer as Accepted if you got the answer.